# Proof of my conjecture on closed form of $\int _{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}e^{-mbx}}{1-e^{-bx}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

Let $a$, $b\in \Bbb R^+$ and $m \in \Bbb N$ then My conjectural closed form is $$\int _{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}e^{-mbx}}{1-e^{-bx}}\,{\rm d}x
=
\frac{\Gamma(a)}{b^a}\left\lbrack\zeta(a)-\sum^{m-1}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^a}\right\rbrack$$
Please tell me how to prove it.

Comment: Expand $1/(1-e^{-bx})$.

Comment: @i707107 How can you exactly explain

Comment: Use $1+e^{-bx}+e^{-2bx}+\cdots$, and integrate term by term.

Comment: How can you conjecture this and yet not being able to prove it? Maybe you do not use the word "conjecture" with its canonical meaning...

Comment: Use the fact that $$n!\cdot\zeta(n)=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^n}{e^t-1}dt$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know what $\zeta(a)$ and $\Gamma(a)$ are, and moreover are able to guess such formula, it is somewhat strange that you are asking for a proof.

Note that $a$ should be actually greater than $1$ for the integral to converge. Under such assumption, we have
\begin{align}
\zeta(a)-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{k^a}&=\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^a}=\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_0^{\infty}x^{a-1}e^{-kx}dx=\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}e^{-mx}}{1-e^{-x}}dx=\\
&=\frac{b^a}{\Gamma(a)}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}e^{-mbx}}{1-e^{-bx}}dx.
\end{align}
*Explanations*:

- Making the change of variables $kx=y$ in the second line transforms the integral into the definition of $\Gamma(a)$ multiplied by $k^{-a}$;
- To pass from the second to the third line we exchange summation and integration and sum the resulting geometric series;
- The fourth line is obtained from the third by the change of variables $x\rightarrow bx$.

Comment: That's a very good proof and the point of asking it is I could get it intuitively but not rigourously.

Comment: @ShivamPatel You say you developed an *intuition* for the formula in the question??

Comment: @Did yes...these things strike to me by intuition. Even when I was 9 , the Eulers formula of $\pi^2/6$ was quite obvious to me,now I am 14 but I am still puzzled why they took so much time for Euler and others to prove it.

Comment: @ShivamPatel Well, well, well...

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{a - 1}\expo{-mbx} \over 1 - \expo{-bx}}\,\dd x
&=
\int _{0}^{\infty}x^{a - 1}\expo{-mbx} \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
\expo{-\ell bx}\,\dd x
=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\int _{0}^{\infty}x^{a - 1} 
\expo{-\pars{m + \ell}bx}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \bracks{\pars{m + \ell}b}^{a}}
\int _{0}^{\infty}x^{a - 1}\expo{-x}\,\dd x
=
{1 \over b^{a}}\sum_{\ell = m}^{\infty}{1 \over \ell^{a}}\Gamma\pars{a}
\\[3mm]&=
{\Gamma\pars{a} \over b^{a}}\pars{%
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \ell^{a}}
-
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{m - 1}{1 \over \ell^{a}}}
=
{\Gamma\pars{a} \over b^{a}}\bracks{%
\zeta\pars{a}
-
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{m - 1}{1 \over \ell^{a}}}
\\[1cm]&
\end{align}

$$\large{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{a - 1}\expo{-mbx} \over 1 - \expo{-bx}}\,\dd x
=
{\Gamma\pars{a} \over b^{a}}\bracks{%
\zeta\pars{a}
-
\sum_{k = 1}^{m - 1}{1 \over k^{a}}}}
$$